# XDocument troble reading XML with <Document> tag (VB.net)

Tags: xml, vb.net, xml-parsing, linq-to-xml

I have a XML file which looks something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Document xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.008.001.02"> 
  <AllThingsInThisDocument> 
    <Headerstuff>
       <Date>2013-06-11</Date>
    </Headerstuff>
    <Reports>
      <Report>
        <Id>01</Id>
        <Name>AA</Name>
      </Report>
      <Report>
        <Id>02</Id>
        <Name>BB</Name>
      </Report>
      <Report>
        <Id>03</Id>
        <Name>CC</Name>
      </Report>
    </Reports>
  </AllThingsInThisDocument> 
</Document>
```

What i want to do is to loop all the reports, i use this code for that:

```
Dim xmlr As XDocument = XDocument.Load("MyMxlFile.xml")
For Each report As XElement In xmlr.Descendants("Report")
   'Do some cool stuff
Next
```

This does how ever not work. What i have found out is that it is the `<Document>` tag that messes this up. If i remove these tags, it understands that i want to do. 
Anybody know why?

**EDIT:** Well, i also just found out that it DOES work with the `<Document>`, it's the xmlns in this case that messes it up. Anyone knows why and/or how to fix this?
It gives me no errors, but it gives me null as result in the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You XML document uses namespace, so you have to use it within your LINQ to XML query.

First of all, create `XNamespace` instance using shared `XNamespace.Get()` method:

```
Dim ns = XNamespace.Get("urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.008.001.02")
```

And then use it in your query using `XNamespace + string` operator:

```
For Each report As XElement In xmlr.Descendants(ns + "Report")
   ' Do some cool stuff '
Next
```